# Maps JavaScript API shapes

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-api

i am trying to use the google maps JavaScript API so that i can draw shapes on the map using (lat , lng ) cord , but i can't pass the location array which have the cords from my node js file to the JavaScript file

here i have an EJS code in which the user input the cords

```
    <form action="/plot"  method="post">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-6">
            <label for="lat">Lat</label>
            <input class="lat" type="text" name="lat"   required>
          </div>
          <div class="col-6">
            <label for="lng">Lng</label>
            <input class="lng"  type="text" name="lng"  required>
          </div>

        <%  location.forEach(function(cord){ %>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-6">
                <label ><%=cord.lat%></label>
              </div>
              <div class="col-6">
                <label ><%=cord.lng%></label>
              </div>

        <%  }) %>

     </form>
          <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary plot_button rtl" type="submit" name="add_button">اضف </button>
```

and then the node js post request is

```
app.post('/plot' , function(req, res){
  var lat =  req.body.lat ;
  var lng = req.body.lng ;

  var locationObj = {lat , lng} ;
  location.push(locationObj);


  res.redirect('/plot');

});
```

so now i have an array called Location contains the cord and i want to pass it in this function in my JavaScript file

```
function initMap() {
  const map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
    zoom: 3,
    center: { lat: 0, lng: -180 },
    mapTypeId: "terrain",
  });
  const flightPlanCoordinates = [     // i want to add the location array here instead of these cords
    { lat: 37.772, lng: -122.214 },
    { lat: 21.291, lng: -157.821 },
    { lat: -18.142, lng: 178.431 },
    { lat: -27.467, lng: 153.027 },
  ];
  const flightPath = new google.maps.Polyline({
    path: flightPlanCoordinates,
    geodesic: true,
    strokeColor: "#FF0000",
    strokeOpacity: 1.0,
    strokeWeight: 2,
  });

  flightPath.setMap(map);
}

window.initMap = initMap;
```

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do to change the hardcoded array with a call from an API, you have to do a `fetch` call and then add it when you get some data from the API.

```js
function initMap() {
  const map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), {
    zoom: 3,
    center: {
      lat: -20,
      lng: -180
    },
    mapTypeId: "terrain",
  });

  fetch('https://mocki.io/v1/79c4f641-d289-4ac2-bcc6-c528bf9a59ed')
    .then((json) => json.json())
    .then(data => {
      const flightPath = new google.maps.Polyline({
        path: data,
        geodesic: true,
        strokeColor: "#FF0000",
        strokeOpacity: 1.0,
        strokeWeight: 2,
      });

      flightPath.setMap(map);
    });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk&callback=initMap" async defer></script>

<div id="map-canvas" style="width: 100%; height: 600px"></div>
```